# AI template needs to be added to cakePHP framework

Tags: php, adobe-illustrator

I have an AI template that was designed for this page but not sure if i need a front end person or a back end person to make the bridge from design to an actual live page using the cake framework... i know there is some documentation on templates using cake, do we slice it up normally and then just add the content to the framework?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CakePHP, like may other web frameworks, has a template system that divided into a few sections (find out more at the [Cake Manual's View page](http://book.cakephp.org/view/94/Views)):

- Layouts: These are templates that makeup the basic layout of the page.
- View Templates: These templates (usually) match a specific action that is taken in the MVC design pattern. For example there may be a view for editing a blog post, and for displaying a blog post. These View templates are injected into a specific section of the Layout template.
- Elements & Helpers: Reusable templates that are injected into View templates, or specific sections of the Layout template. An 'author' template may be inserted into an article View template, or a login box may be displayed in a section of the Layout template.

I'll admit that I don't do much with CakePHP, but these concepts are similar across many frameworks.

> do we slice it up normally and then just add the content to the framework

When slicing you'll need to keep the different kinds of templates in mind. Slice up the common elements into a Layout Template. Slice up the action specific portions into small View Templates designed to be inserted into the Layout Template. Slice common dynamic elements into Helper/Element Templates.

> not sure if i need a front end person or a back end person to make the bridge from design to an actual live page using the cake framework

Someone with front end experience will be able to create the templates, but you'll need someone with backend experience to create the Controllers (the code that *does* whatever it is your site *does*) and tie everything together.

Answer (score 1):

What Tim says, and: You basically have two steps here. One is converting the AI document into good, wisely built HTML. This is most likely a task for a web/interface designer who does not necessarily know Cake.

Then you need somebody to make that HTML structure into a Cake template. This is most likely a task for a programmer who knows Cake, but is not necessarily a full-blown web/interface designer.

The web designer and the cake template maker *can* be the same person; Anyway, they should be in close contact. The Cake person will have input for the HTML person that will influence the work from the start.

Comment: Was updating my answer to address the specific concerns when you answered. Didn't mean to steal (the essence of) your answer and put it in mine.

Comment: @Tim no problem, I didn't assume you were.

Comment: thx both-- 

btw, do you know where images are stored using cake? ill look it up in the manual or google just thought you might be able to help